# raise exception en plpgsql cuando el argumento esté vacío

Tags: plpgsql

Tengo este código acabado, lo único que me falta es que salte un mensaje cuando la función se ejecute sin ningún tipo de argumento, y no lo acabo de conseguir, aquí os dejo el código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comptaprofes(id_departament integer) RETURNS void AS $$

DECLARE

    data_compta date;
    departament DECIMAL(5);
    quantitat DECIMAL(5);

BEGIN

    select cod_dep
    into departament
    from departaments
    where id_departament = cod_dep;

    IF id_departament is null THEN
        raise exception 'El valor es nul';

    ELSIF NOT FOUND THEN 
        raise exception 'El departament no existeix';

    ELSE
        select count(cod_professor)
        into quantitat
        from professors
        where id_departament = cod_dep;

        select current_date
        into data_compta;

        insert into 
            numeroprofes (data_compta, departament, quantitat) 
        values (data_compta, departament, quantitat);

    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías crear otra función sin argumentos con el mismo nombre y cuando sea invocada lanzar el error.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comptaprofes() RETURNS void 
AS $$

BEGIN
   raise exception "Por favor indique un argumento";
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Si invocas a la función comptaprofes(id_departament integer) y no le pasas el argumento postgres no encuentra esa función.

Saludos"

Comment: Hola Blasito, bienvenido. Esta respuesta es de muy baja calidad, parece un comentario. Podrías añadir el codigo para que sea mejor. Un saludo

Comment: Corregido!!  Tengo poco tiempo y quise ayudar. Saludos!

Comment: Vale, habría forma pero, de tenerlo todo hecho en una sola función?

Comment: Cuando defines una función con argumentos necesariamente al llamarlo debes especificar el parámetro ya que si no lo haces no llega a ejecutarse la función ya que postgres no lo encuentra, por eso es difícil validarlo dentro de ella.